# Lightning - OpenSubTab in Service console app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I am trying openSubTab on a service console application when user click on the member name. When I do so it giving error which i am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Could you please shed some light on this. Household Members is a custom object having lookup relationship with Contact. "Household members" is a custom component.

### Component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="CC_HouseholdMemberController">

    <aura:attribute name="contactId" type="Id"/>
    <aura:attribute name="hhmbrs" type="HouseholdMember__c[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="ComponentLabel" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
    <tbody>
       <aura:iteration items="{!v.hhmbrs}" var="hm">
          <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
             <td>
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!hm.MemberName__c}">
                   <lightning:button onclick = "{!c.openTabWithSubtab}"/>
                   <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="{!hm.Member__c}" aura:id="{!hm.Member__c}" onclick="{!c.openTabWithSubtab}">
                   {!hm.MemberName__c}
                   </a>
                </div>
             </td>
             <td>
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!hm.AccountTypeFormula__c}">{!hm.AccountTypeFormula__c}</div>
             </td>
             <td>
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!hm.RelationshipFormula__c}">{!hm.RelationshipFormula__c}</div>
             </td>
          </tr>
       </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
```

### Controller

```
        openTabWithSubtab : function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        console.log("workspaceID@@"+workspaceAPI); 
        var recTempId = component.get("v.recordId");
        console.log("recordID@@"+recTempId);        
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
           var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
                parentTabId: focusedTabId,                
                recordId : recTempId,
                focus: true
            });          
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you use pageReference? Also what is State? there is no param in openSubTab method names State.

Comment: Thanks , thats a good catch. I had updated my code but it still didn't work.

Comment: @user28452 Can you make sure your question body reflects the current state of your code and the current error you're seeing? Maybe also include any console output you're seeing.

Comment: do you have <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/> in your component?

Comment: @Calvin : Yes I do have that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to comment saying "Your code works on my org." Then I realized you are getting the recordId wrong. Well, technically you are getting the Id of already opened record. (DAWN HICKS record) That is why you are getting could not open subtab error. A tab with that record is already opened and it cant open same record tab inside.

Instead of this:

```
var recTempId = component.get("v.recordId");
```

it should be this:

```
var recTempId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me to realize my mistake that I have to pass Member__c  Id value to open as subtab and NOT parent contact Id itself(which is why i am getting error). The following did the trick for me as I have to retrive HTML attributes.  var recTempId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id');